# How to get statistics of all samples through statistics of subsamples?

Tags: r, descriptive-statistics

I know the statistics of several subgroups.

For example,

1. Mean, variance, standard deviation, and number of group A
2. Mean, variance, standard deviation, and number of group B

Group C = Group A + Group B

With this information, can you find the mean, variance, standard deviation, and number of group C?

Assuming that the values of each group are unknown

Comment: is 'number' a statistic? If so, what is it?

Comment: @Dayne 'number' is the count of elements in the group.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is C the disjoint union of A and B? If so, then

count(C) = count(A) + count(B)
sum(C) = sum(A) + sum(B)
sum(c^2 | c in C) = sum(a^2 | a in A) + sum(b^2 | b in B)

From these, you can work out mean, variance, and standard deviation.

Alternatively, are you wanting to estimate the statistics of a population C, based on samples of subpopulations A and B? That is more complicated, but searching for "Capture Re-capture" will give you a head start.

Comment: Can you give more explanation for sum(a^2 | a in A)? The expression (a^2 | a in A) is not well understood.

Comment: The sum of the square of elements in A.